# Concat Avro files in Google Cloud Storage

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, avro, gsutil, avro-tools

I have some big `.avro` files in the Google Cloud Storage and I want to concat all of them in a single file.

I got

`java -jar avro-tools.jar concat`

However, as my files are in the google storage path: `gs://files.avro` I can't concat them by using avro-tools. Any suggestion about how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`gsutil compose`](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/compose) command. For example:

```
gsutil compose gs://bucket/obj1 [gs://bucket/obj2 ...] gs://bucket/composite
```

> Note: For extremely large files and/or very low per-machine bandwidth, you may want to split the file and upload it from multiple machines, and later compose these parts of the file manually.

On my case I tested it with the following values: **foo.txt** contains a word *Hello* and **bar.txt** contains a word *World*. Running this command:

```
gsutil compose gs://bucket/foo.txt gs://bucket/bar.txt gs://bucket/baz.txt
```

**baz.txt** would return:

```
Hello
World
```

> Note: GCS does not support inter-bucket composing.

Just in case if you're encountering an exception error with regards to [integrity checks](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/composite-objects#integrity-checking), run `gsutil help crcmod` to get an instructions on how to fix it.

Comment: It's a very nice option! However, is it useful for avro? (due to headers)

Comment: There isn't any flag yet that allows you to skip headers and for that, an alternative is you may have to write your own app to process the concatenation. Other [users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57591243/how-to-use-gsutil-compose-in-googleshell-and-skip-first-rows) have done it on their use case with csv.

Answer (score 1):

Check out https://github.com/spotify/gcs-tools

> Light weight wrapper that adds Google Cloud Storage (GCS) support to common Hadoop tools, including **avro-tools**, parquet-cli, proto-tools for Scio's Protobuf in Avro file, and magnolify-tools for Magnolify code generation, so that they can be used from regular workstations or laptops, outside of a Google Compute Engine (GCE) instance.